# Backbone when to build logic into view vs having separate view

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

So I know there are many ways for doing things in Backbone, but since I don't have the vast experience of many on here, I would like advice regarding a best approach.

I have a basic CRUD app where I have a form for adding data and a form for editing data, which are essentially the same. And actually are attached to the same DOM element.

So I could include the two forms into one view and serve the appropriate template, depending on whether the view has a model or not. Something like this:

```
var AddEditView = Backbone.View.extend ({
el: $("#add"),
template: $("editTemplate").html();
render: function() {
    if (this.model) {
        var theTmp = _.template(this.template)
        this.$el.html(theTmp(this.model.toJSON()));
    }
    else {
        var theTmp = _.template($("#addTemplate").html());
        this.$el.html(theTmp);
    }
},
```

});
I think this would work however I might run into some sticky issues with any events (i.e. events being bound twice).

Or I could create two completely separate views that would be attached to the same dom element and would toggle back and forth depending on the app state (way more lines of code).

What would you all recommend in this situation. Is more logic in a view better or more lines of code and less logic in views?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the fields are identical whether you're creating a new model or editing an existing one, I'd recommend having only one view, and only one template. When you instantiate the view, if you are creating a new model, just instantiate a new model and pass it to the view. Otherwise, pass the existing model.

```
var AddEditView = Backbone.View.extend ({
    render: function() {
        var theTmp = _.template(this.template)
        this.$el.html(theTmp(this.model.toJSON()));
    },
    someSaveEvent: function() {
        this.model.save(); // This will POST if the model isNew() or PUT otherwise
    }
});

var model = new Model(); // If you're creating a new model

var addEditView = new AddEditView({
    model: model
});
```

Comment: I was kind of thinking about that as well but if I have default values on the model, the template will be populated with those default values, right?